# parsing a xml file

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file as:

```
<one>
 <a>sth</a>
 <b>sth</b>
 <c>sth</c>
</one>
<one>
 <a>x</a>
 <b>y</b>
 <c>z</c>
</one>
```

what i want is to retrieve the names "a", "b", "c" from the xml, i.e the child under the node "one", using xml.dom

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: what i tried is:


'
from xml.dom import minidom
dom = minidom.parse('sth.xml')
detailList = dom.getElementsByTagName('one')[0].childNodes
for each in detailList:
  print each.tagName
'

Comment: it's not a valid xml file it should have one root

Comment: actually the file i am trying to parse is a hiab scan report (xml)
i have parsed it as well, i just couldnt find the way to get the tagName for the elements inside the node "one". i tried with the above code with no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML file should like format such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ones>
<one>
 <a>sth</a>
 <b>sth</b>
 <c>sth</c>
</one>
<one>
 <a>x</a>
 <b>y</b>
 <c>z</c>
</one>
</ones>
```

You can try the follow code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse('filePath')
root = xmldoc.documentElement

ones = root.getElementsByTagName('one')

L = []
for one in ones:
    m = {}
    #print onn.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    #print n.getElementsByTagName('b')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    #print n.getElementsByTagName('c')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    for n in one.childNodes:
         if n.nodeType == n.ELEMENT_NODE:
                 m[n.nodeName] =n.firstChild.nodeValue
    L.append(m)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now if I want to make a list of dicts as
[{'a' : sth, 'b' : sth, 'c' : sth}, {'a' : x, 'b' : y, 'c' : z}]
which means i dont know the tag names in advance and i want to read all the data present, tagname : value, what should i do?

Comment: I change the code, you can try it

Answer (score 3):

Check out `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html